# Sorting and splitting a txt file in Linux based on how many times a particular line is repeated

Tags: linux, sorting, split, command

I have a 3 GB txt file:

```
Lucy
Mary 
Lily 
John 
Mary 
Ann
John 
Lily
Lily
Mary
Lucy 
Mark
```

In the output, there must be files like:

3instances.txt:

```
Lily
Lily
Lily
Mary 
Mary
Mary
```

2instances.txt:

```
John 
John 
Lucy
Lucy
```

1instance.txt:

```
Ann
Mark
```

Comment: Hi. Are you sure you want to repeat `"Lily"` three times in the `3instances.txt` file? It's a bit redundant. The file is already called `3instances.txt`. If you write `"Lily"` only once in it it's clear that it stands for 3 repetitions.

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat "Lily" three times in the 3instances.txt file

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the shell, you can use the following, assuming no name contains whitespaces:

```
awk '{$1=$1; print $1}' INPUT_FILE | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 > $1"instances.txt"}'
```

`awk '{$1=$1; print $1}'`: trim whitespaces

`sort`: to group equal names

`uniq -c`: to count unique repeated lines and print count, ie.  `1 Alice`

`awk '{ print $2 > $1"instances.txt"}`: to write names (2nd column) to a file, based on count (1st column)

---

Will produce:

1instances.txt

```
Ann
Mark
.
.
.
```

2instances.txt

```
John
Lucy
.
.
.
```

3instances.txt

```
Lily
Mary
.
.
.
```

Comment: I tried this with their data but it didn't work as desired, since some of their lines have additional spaces so they don't match the lines without them.

Comment: That's right. I've changed the answer to take care of that.

Comment: Ah darn, I was hoping there's a simple `trim` command or so :-)

Answer (score 0):

There exist some wizards who could do these kinds of things with `awk` and other shell commands.

For ordinary people, there is python.

Please note I have tested the following code on your small example, but not on a 3GB file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import Counter
import sys

def group_by_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        c = Counter(line.strip() for line in f)
    groups = {}
    for (line, count) in c.items():
        groups.setdefault(count, []).append(line)
    return groups

def write_files(groups):
    for n, lines in sorted(groups.items()):
        filename = f'{n}instances.txt'
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line + '\n')

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) > 1:
        groups = group_by_count(argv[1])
        write_files(groups)
    else:
        print('Please specify a file name to read from.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Results:

```
$ chmod +x sort_by_repetitions.py
$ cat test.txt
Lucy
Mary 
Lily 
John 
Mary 
Ann
John 
Lily
Lily
Mary
Lucy 
Mark
$ ./sort_by_repetitions.py test.txt
$ ls *instances*
1instances.txt  2instances.txt  3instances.txt
$ cat 1instances.txt 
Ann
Mark
$ cat 2instances.txt 
Lucy
John
$ cat 3instances.txt 
Mary
Lily
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    {
        cnt[$0]++
    }
    END{
        n=asorti(cnt, sorted); 
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            out = cnt[sorted[i]] (cnt[sorted[i]]>1 ? "instances.txt" : "instance.txt")
            for (j=1; j<=cnt[sorted[i]]; j++) 
                print sorted[i] > out     
        } 
}' file

$ head ?instance*.txt
==> 1instance.txt <==
Ann
Mark

==> 2instances.txt <==
John
John
Lucy
Lucy

==> 3instances.txt <==
Lily
Lily
Lily
Mary
Mary
Mary
```